# Are dvijas allowed to touch dogs?

Tags: dharma, dharma-shastras

What happens if a dvija touches a dog? If it's sinful what is the prayaschitta? If it causes asaucha what is the method of purification?

Comment: fyi, Yudhishthira was a dvija, and while ascending to svarga, he had a dog all the way.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - did Yudhishtira touch the dog ? Also, the dog was incarnation of Yama dharmaraj, If one's house pet jimmy/tommy is also yama dharma raj, they can touch it. FYI, Muslims consider dogs unclean too - if you touch one, you can't go to masjid before bathing.

Comment: Tbh, I would care less what other religions have to say something on any matter. In any case, I got the answer from the accepted one. :-) @mar

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - the reason I mentioned Islam is that many young supposedly 'right-wing' traditional people feel the need to differentiate Hinduism from Islam at any cost - even if it means disregarding their own shastras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Dogs are considered unclean as per vedas**

> [Shatapatha Brahmana 12:4:1:4](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe44/sbe44058.htm) :
>
> *4. 'But, surely, there are three **unclean animals**, a vicious boar, a vicious ram  and a **dog**: if any one of these runs about between
> (the fires) whilst the Agnihotra-offering is put on (the fire), what
> rite and what expiation would there be in that case?'*
>
> [Shatapatha Brahmana 14:1:1:31](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe44/sbe44117.htm):
>
> *31. And whilst not coming into contact with Sûdras and remains of food; for this Gharma is he that shines yonder, and he is excellence,
> truth, and light; but woman, the Sûdra, the **dog**, and the black
> bird (the crow), are **untruth**: he should not look at these, lest he
> should mingle excellence and sin, light and darkness, truth and
> untruth.*

**Expiation for dvijas due to physical contact with dogs  as per padmapurANa & garuDapurANa**

> [padmapurANa-shrishtikhanda-ch48](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc364171.html):
>
> *32. A man should bathe after having **touched (i.e. if he touches)** a fallen man, or a leper, or a cāṇḍāla eating the flesh of cows, or
> **a dog**, or a woman in her menses, or a bhilla.*
>
> [garuDapurANa-dhanvantrisamhita-ch.CCXXXI](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122711.html) :
>
> *A Brahmana having **touched a dog**, a shudra, or any other beast, or a woman in her menses, before washing his face after a meal, shall
> regain his purity by fasting for a day, and by taking Panchagavyam.*

**yudhishthira dog story does not invalidate any of the above as that story is about sacrifice for a dependent living being during final stage of life  and not impurities associated with dogs**

> *"Yudhishthira said, ‘It has been said that the **abandonment of one
> that is devoted is infinitely sinful**. It is equal to the sin that
> one incurs by slaying a Brahmana*.

Comment: Thanks. In the second Brahmana citation, it puts women and shudras in the same category as dogs, but that's only in the context of the pravargya ritual where they should not be looked at. Obviously outside of that we can touch women (and outside of menstruation).

Comment: Also, how come the garuda purana offers a more difficult prayaschitta compared to the padma purana? Fasting and drinking panchagavyam versus taking a bath.

Comment: Garuda purana is specifically referring to brahmana whereas padma purana appears to be generic (all men/dvijas), maybe thats the reason for extra penance

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: What about this part "before washing his face after a meal"? That sounds like a random interjection.

Comment: the same chapter also has these verses which wd explain that - _A Brahmana, with his face unwashed after a meal, happening to be touched by a shudra, similarly circumstanced as himself, or by a dog, shall regain his purity by fasting for a night, and by taking the compound known as Panchagavyam,_